# How to protect a specific record

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, claims-based-identity

We are trying to write an authorization program to our company.

We've decided to use [`claim based authorization`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims) .

The normal restrictions are pretty easy (Let particular users use particular services ETC) , but I have some kind of special requirement :

- I need to filter records of the result set, based on the claim this user have.

For example , I have a service that return a list of people that invest in our company, with details about them and the amount of money they have. Now, an employee **shouldn't** be able to see other employee details, **unless** this employee is a direct manager of the employee presented.

This means -> I need the claim attribute to some how effect the result set, and I couldn't find any information online on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is usually called **fine-grain security**, and [HERE](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAk8Dep9LWAhWPdSYKHSC_DYcQFghNMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgeekswithblogs.net%2Fshahed%2Farchive%2F2010%2F02%2F05%2F137795.aspx&usg=AOvVaw2pSBiSamXa-kjpezcX7CtP) is one article on doing it with ASP.Net and claims.  Also, [a search for "asp.net fine grained permissions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net%20mvc%20fine%20grained%20permissions&oq=asp.net%20fine-gr&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l2.5841j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) will lead you to lots of resources.

This is a pretty involved topic, but it basically involves elegant and effective ways to add filters (e.g. `WHERE` clauses on SQL queries) to accomplish your row-level application security.